# With wxPython, How can I get an event from a popup menu to the calling window?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I've been working on getting data from a popup menu back to another control. I've setup a custom menu class, and from there I catch the EVT_MENU, and raise another custom event so I can return some customized data from the menu, rather than just the menu item id or text.

The problem I'm running into is that the event handler I've bound to the custom event I'm creating isn't being called. Here's a distilled example that displays the behavior in question.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self._showMenu)

        self.Bind(RClickMenu.EVT_CHANGE, self._eventReciever)

    def _eventReciever(self, evt):
        print 'notified'

    def _showMenu(self, evt):
        pos = evt.GetPosition()
        pos = self.panel.ScreenToClient(pos)
        self.panel.PopupMenu(RClickMenu(), pos)

class RClickMenu(wx.Menu):
    ChangeEvent, EVT_CHANGE = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
    vals = (('Item 1', 8),
            ('Item 2', None))

    def __init__(self):
        super(RClickMenu, self).__init__()
        for name, val in self.vals:
            item = self.Append(wx.ID_ANY, name)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self._notify, item)

    def _notify(self, event):
        item = self.FindItemById(event.GetId())
        text = item.GetText()
        for name, val in self.vals:
            if name == text:
                value = val
                break

        print 'do_notify'
        evt = self.ChangeEvent(value=value)
        wx.PostEvent(self, evt)

app = wx.App(False)
Example(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

What I'm seeing is that RClickMenu._notify is being called, but the event it raises, RClickMenu.EVT_CHANGE is never picked in Example, so Example._eventReciever is never called. Any ideas as to why?

**Edit:** So it seems this is a parenting issue, where the RClickMenu or the popup menu that's created with Panel.PopupMenu isn't technically a child of Example. I'd still much rather be able to do something in the nature of this example, but for now I'm just creating the wx.Menu and populating it inside of Example, and catching the wx.EVT_MENU there. Not really ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Events are not propagated to the parent by default, only the objects of `wxCommandEvent` and derived classes propagate. So to let another event, such as your custom `EVT_CHANGE`, propagate to its parent frame from the menu, you need to set `event.m_propagationLevel`, if this is wrapped by wxPython, or call [ResumePropagation()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_event.html#a0acb5c75f6e67b8822ad8ba3c5bdc4fe).

But the simplest solution might be to just handle the original `EVT_MENU` (which is a command event and thus does propagate) in the parent. Or even ditch the events completely and use [GetPopupMenuSelectionFromUser()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a00f5cb3cac003205317a565a33d4bb27) directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the calling object into the class instantiation as an argument like so.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

app_event_popup_item_activated, APP_EVENT_POPUP_ITEM_ACTIVATED = wx.lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent()

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self._showMenu)
        self.Bind(APP_EVENT_POPUP_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.on_popup_item_activated)


    def _showMenu(self, evt):
        pos = evt.GetPosition()
        pos = self.panel.ScreenToClient(pos)
        self.panel.PopupMenu(Popup(self), pos)        

    def on_popup_item_activated(self, event):
        print "Popup item clicked"

class Popup(wx.Menu):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Menu.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent

        item = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.NewId(), "Click ME")
        self.AppendItem(item)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_menu_item_activated, item)

    def on_menu_item_activated(self, event):
        post_event = app_event_popup_item_activated(APP_EVENT_POPUP_ITEM_ACTIVATED.typeId)
        wx.PostEvent(self.parent, post_event)

app = wx.App(False)
Example(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

The command event will propagate up to the parent. Even though the parent inst a parent in the same way a frame and a panel would be a parent and child, the parent we pass in can still receive command events directly.